# Голосовать за свои сообщения на мете

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, мета, голосование

Бывает, что предлагаешь к (своему) вопросу охапку вариантов ответа и хочется за один из них проголосовать, но нельзя, поскольку ответ собственный. Кажется, для меты этот запрет несколько нелогичен в данном случае?

Comment: Голосуй, не голосуй все равно получишь *сообщение об ошибке*.

Comment: Связанный вопрос, кстати: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3600

Answer (score 9):

Предлагаю подумать дальше первой реакции "хочу".

1. Порядок ответов оказывает влияние на голоса. Если разрешить голосовать за свой ответ, нужно будет или усложнять логику сортировки, которая и без того не всегда очевидна, или разрешать голосовать за себя после некоторой задержки, например, в 8 часов, что можно легко обойти, оставляя ответ в ночное время.
2. На Мете тоже выдаются значки и существует репа, хоть она и не отображается. Если разрешить голосовать за себя, придётся усложнять логику для расчётов на всех сайтах, а она и без того сложная и с багами.
3. Голосование за свой ответ имеет практическую пользу только в вопросах-голосовалках. Как их отличать? Добавить в интерфейс ещё одну галочку? Это испортит гармонию минимализма, вон, даже галку для вики-постов убрали.

И всё ради чего? Чтобы автор мог добавить один голос, который на активном сайте, вообще говоря, должен быть статистической погрешностью? Игра не стоит свеч.

Comment: 1. А что плохого, если ответ немного поднимется за счёт собственного голоса? Это как раз и есть цель голосования - иначе зачем бы? 2. А что даёт репа на мете? 3. Можно и без галочки - если пользователь даёт не менее двух ответов на вопрос, то он может голосовать за ответ. Да или вообще, пусть всегда может - вопросы-голосовалки тут достаточно популярны.

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. Первые голоса — часто решающие. Если оценку автор будет давать сразу, это может заметно сказаться на результатах. 2. Значки.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Discord, в особенности в выводах. Если сообщество большое, один голос – это погрешность. Если сообщество небольшое, вы можете просто оставить комментарий под ответом и он будет учтен (в случае «большого» сообщества, по правде говоря, он буден учтен тоже).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, если немного изменить формулировку - "голосовать за свои **общие** ответы", то проблема с накруткой репутации отпадает.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите, чтобы какой-то вариант получил больше голосов, то самый лучший способ – понятно и убедительно его аргументировать. Расскажите всем, почему нужно выбрать именно тот вариант, который вы предпочитаете. Можете также написать о его преимуществах в сравнении с другими вариантами. Если вы всё сделаете правильно, это принесёт вашему ответу гораздо больше, чем один голос.

Comment: Если немного изменить формулировку - "голосовать за свои **общие** ответы", то проблема с накруткой репутации отпадает.