# Как было задумано, так и оставить

Tags: обсуждение, использование-метки

Думаю, метки [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [статус-так-задумано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be) не должны [использоваться вместе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE)?

Эти предложения именно для того вносились, чтобы изменить текущую реализацию:
[Голосовать за свои сообщения на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1624/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5)
[Показывать некоторые свои принятые ответы первыми](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1614/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Так почему бы не поставить им ответную метку [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be)?

Comment: В одном вопросе было нагромождение всех системных тегов, поправил. По остальным вопросам согласен, [meta-tag:статус-отклонено] лучше подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Моя ошибка. Поправил упомянутые вами вопросы.